# Play Framework with React in Webjar

Tags: scala, reactjs, webjars

What I am looking for is a way to make the development with Play and React happens smoothly. I was hoping that if I use ReactJS in Webjar, there would be a way that I can use JSX transformer in development, and have the JSX compiled in production, i.e. when I run `activator dist` command. Is there a way to achieve such a development workflow?

Here is my build.sbt

```
name := "play-scala"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "org.webjars.bower" % "react" % "0.13.1"
)
```

and here is a sample scala template react.scala.html

```
@main("React in Webjar") {

    <div id="content"></div>

    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/react/react.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/react/JSXTransformer.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/reactApp.jsx")" type="text/jsx"></script>
}
```

I am using a Bower Webjars. I wonder if that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a jsx compilation plugin that you can use to compile .jsx files into .js, for example this: https://github.com/ddispaltro/sbt-reactjs

You will then need to use different import blocks in your templates depending on if running as in dev or prod, something like this:

```
@if(play.api.Play.current.mode == play.api.Mode.Prod) {
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/react/react.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/reactApp.js")" type="text/jsx"></script>
} else {
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/react/react.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/react/JSXTransformer.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/reactApp.jsx")" type="text/jsx"></script>
}
```

More elaborate setups can be achieved using requirejs and other module managing schemes, but this is the simplest solution in a small project IMHO.

Comment: This works! If only there is a better way than using the if statement for every view. Thanks!

Comment: You could create a separate template (like a fragment) that you call everywhere instead, or some variation on that theme. The paths you give to the jsx-files are just strings so you can do string manipulation replacing ".jsx" with ".js" for example.

Comment: Great idea! And that is totally doable.